# Update list of data in room database column

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

I have a list of data and i want to update in room database column but I can't find any method to update my data

```
@Query("UPDATE student_db")
default void update(List<Student> student) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (**see notes/comments**)

```
@Update
int update(List<Student> student)
```

- as long as the Student's in the list are ALL set with the appropriate values especially that the PrimaryKey field/member is correct as Room determines the Student(s) to update according to the PrimaryKey.

If using `@Query` then you have to be more specific about what is to be updated *(the convenience `@Update` covers common scenarios not all)*.

If you used

```
@Query("UPDATE student_db SET the_column=:the_new_value")
void update(String the_new_value);
```

The this would **update ALL rows** with the same value (as there is no WHERE clause).

To update a single student (assuming the primary key field/member) then you could use:-

```
@Query("UPDATE student_db SET the_column=:the_new_value WHERE id=:id")
void update(String the_new_value, long id);
```

If you want to have a method with a body (as you appear to want) then instead of using an interface use an abstract class (you cannot have methods with bodies in an interface).

e.g.

```
@Dao
abstract class theDao {

    @Query("UPDATE student_db SET the_column=:the_new_value WHERE id=:id ")
    abstract void update(String the_new_value,long id)

    @Transaction
    @Query("")
    abstract default void update(List<Student> student) {
      for(Student s: student) {
          update("The new value for this student",s.id);
      }
    }
}
```

- `@Trasnaction` as in the example multiple updates are executed
- `Query("")` to fool room into handling the entire method as being in a transaction.